# Specify element in foreach jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach, each, google-datalayer

I am trying to do a .each function to push an impression for each product on a search results page into a dataLayer. I am having a hard time figuring out how to specify the $(this) element in my foreach. I am not sure this is best way to do what I want, so if anyone has a better way of doing this, please let me know :)

Hope I am making sense!
Thanks!

```js
<script>
 $(function () {
            $(".result-price-carpark-name span, .result-price-actual").each(function(index) {
            console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).text() );
            var carpark = $(this).text(); //How to specify its $(this) inside the .result-price-carpark-name span??
            var price = $(this).text(); //How to specify its $(this) inside the .result-price-actual??
            
             dataLayer.push({
            'ecommerce': {
            'currencyLocal': 'USD',
            'impressions': [{
            'name': carpark,
            'id': carpark,
            'price': price,
            'category': carpark,
            'list': 'ParkAstro',
            'position': ''
            }]
            }
            })
            })
        });

</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="result-prices-item">
<div class="result-price-carpark-name"><span>PARK1</span></div>
<div class="result-price-actual">22</div>
</div>

<div class="result-prices-item">
<div class="result-price-carpark-name"><span>PARK2</span></div> 
<div class="result-price-actual">22</div>
</div>

<div class="result-prices-item">
<div class="result-price-carpark-name"><span>PARK3</span></div> 
<div class="result-price-actual">22</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to loop through each carpark item, then you need to loop through each carpark item (ie, not the children). Then, inside that loop, you can get the children (aka the name and price for that specific item) by using the optional [context parameter](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context).

```
$(".result-prices-item").each(function() {
    $('.result-price-carpark-name', this).text();
    $('.result-price-actual', this).text();
});
```

etc.

Comment: Yes, why not? :) That was exactly what I was looking for, just wasn't sure how to do it. Thanks!